# How to return all departments which have no female employees and the number of male employees

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Given a database design similar to the following:

```
EMPLOYEE: ID, Gender, Salary, DEPT_ID
```

I have written the following "pseudo-SQL" in an effort to illustrate the output I want, I am trying to simultaneously find the count of female and male employees, then filter to just the ones with no female employees, and finally return the number of males in that department.

```
SELECT males, dno FROM
(SELECT COUNT(Gender = 'male') AS males, COUNT(Gender = 'female') AS females, DEPT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Dno)
WHERE females = 0;
```

This is not valid COUNT syntax but hopefully can serve as an illustration.

Comment: Does it work? If not then its not the right SQL. Also, what you want is not clear. Number of males and departments? That sounds like two separate queries. Do you want the number of males in departments where no females work?

Comment: It's not valid syntax because [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions046.htm#SQLRF00624) doesn't accept Boolean expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT DNO, SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MALE
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY DNO
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0) = 0;
```

It counts the number of male and female employees for each department and then selects those where female count is 0;

Comment: `case` requires an `end` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming people are either only male or female, this might be the simplest solution:

```
SELECT Dno, COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Dno
HAVING SUM(gender = 'female') = 0;
```

The `count(*)` returns the number of males.  If there are no females, then everyone is a male -- hence the full count.

You can be more explicit by doing

```
SELECT Dno, SUM(gender = 'male')
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Dno
HAVING SUM(gender = 'female') = 0;
```

EDIT:

The sample code in the question is inconsistent with the Oracle tag (which I don't think was on the question when I originally answered it).  Assuming that there are only two genders, then the simplest method in Oracle is:

```
SELECT Dno, COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Dno
HAVING MIN(gender) = 'male';
```

This, incidentally, is ANSI-standard syntax and will work in any database.

Comment: `sum(gender = 'female')`? That would be a lovely syntax, if Oracle SQL had Booleans.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson . . . The *sample code* in the question uses this syntax.  It was not tagged Oracle when I answered it.

Comment: I noticed that, but I just assumed the OP had guessed the syntax and not tested it. I suppose if MySQL or something casts Boolean expressions to integers, then summing them as in your example would work (while counting them as in the OP's example would not).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson . . . That is MySQL syntax.  It is one of the few extensions to SQL that I regularly use (even when an alternative is available).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select dno, count(*) as non_female_staff
from   employee
group by dno
having count(case when gender = 'female' then 1 end) = 0;

       DNO NON_FEMALE_STAFF
---------- ----------------
         3                6
```

Or maybe something like this for a fuller picture:

```
select dno
     , count(*)
     , count(case when gender = 'female' then 1 end) as female_staff
     , round(100 * count(case when gender = 'female' then 1 end) / count(*)) as female_percentage
from   employee
group by dno;

       DNO   COUNT(*) FEMALE_STAFF FEMALE_PERCENTAGE
---------- ---------- ------------ -----------------
         1          4            1                25
         2          4            3                75
         3          6            0                 0
```